# How to run a UCMA 4.0 trusted application on a separate application server?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ucma

I'm not an Unified Communications developer and my head is thumping.

I have three virtual computers (Windows Server 2012 R2) that are joined to the domain. They are pingable among themselves and two Lync clients on VM#2 and VM#3 can talk to each other:

- VM#1 AD DC
- VM#2 Lync 2013 Server
- VM#3 Application Server

The UCMA application is supposed to run on VM#3 that is also my development environment (Visual Studio and UMCA 4.0 SDK are installed). But then I can't start the collaboration platform with ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings since I get a ProvisioningFailureException that says that somebody was "unable to find the Sqld database".

I followed "General application activation" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466115(v=office.15).aspx step by step. **Question 1:** Do I have to execute these PowerShell cmdlets on VM#2 or VM#3?

I do not know what database the exception is talking about. **Question 2:** Is it looking for a local database that should be in sync with the Central Management Store on VM#2?

**Question 3:** I read about installing Central Management Store replication service by running Bootstrapper.exe /BootstrapLocalMgmt /MinCache. When do I need replication in my system? Is that an optional thing?

**Post update:**

When I execute the New-CsTrustedApplicationPool and Enable-CsTopology cmdlets on VM#2, Get-CsManagementStoreReplicationStatus will display two entries:

UpToDate        : True
ReplicationFqdn : LYNCSERVER.artus.demo

and

UpToDate        : False
ReplicationFqdn : APPSERVER.artus.demo

**Question 1.1:** UpToDate should be set to **True** after executing Enable-CsReplica and Invoke-CsManagementStoreReplication cmdlets, shouldn't it? Does the second entry mean a Local Management Store that is located in VM#2?

**Question 1.2:** Are the following parameters correct?

- New-CsTrustedApplicationPool -Identity trustedapps.artus.demo
  -Registrar Registrar:LYNCSERVER.artus.demo -Site Site:DemoSite1 -ComputerFqdn APPSERVER.artus.demo;

**Question 3.1:** On what VM do I have to run Bootstrapper.exe /BootstrapLocalMgmt /MinCache. I think this was automatically done during Lync Server 2013 installation on VM#3 and I can't imagine that on VM#2 Lync Server 2013 core components have to be installed.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question #1:** It Depends on the command. If you are referring to the new-csTrustedApplicationPool, new-csTrustedApplication,enable-cstopology and new-csTrustedApplicationEndpoint commands then they need to be run on vm#2 your Lync 2013 server.  Request-CSCertificate needs to be run on vm#3 your application server.

**(Response To Update)**  So I guess APPSERVER.artus.demo is the name of vm #3.  You need to run the boot-strapper on it to allow replication to work.

**Question #2:**Yes it's the CMS Db, looking at question 3 it sounds as if you haven't run bootstrapper.

**Question #3:**  Have never deployed a UCMA service without replication although it can be done.  Have seen people try to turn off replication on the application pool and it fail.  Regardless for a first time install it's not optional.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you review my notes, please?